# QGIS crash Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis

Encountering a crash when requesting QGIS 2.2 to access data on desktop machine. Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
$ qgis
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_AU]
qgis.bin(32381)/KSharedDataCache KSharedDataCache::Private::mapSharedMemory: Failed to establish shared memory mapping, will fallback to private memory -- memory usage will increase 
kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4: ERROR creating database '/home/lyndon/.kde/cache-Gerhard-ThinkPad-W530/ksycoca4'! Insufficient permissions in target directory.
Warning: ERROR: Running KSycoca failed.
QGIS died on signal 11ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No thread selected
No stack.
gdb returned 0
Aborted (core dumped)'
```

Any request, such as opening a file, browsing, creating a new project etc. will cause this crash.

I am new to QGIS and will eagerly post additional information, if provided instructions.

EDIT:

output of:

```
sudo ls -l /home/lyndon/.kde/cache-Gerhard-ThinkPad-W530/


total 10320 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10547304 Apr 25 2013 icon-cache.kcache –
```

EDIT:

running QGIS desktop as root does allow me to open files! But it also pops up with an error message immediately after the program runs (ie after the initial loading/welcome graphic dissapears):

**The layer /usr/share/applications/%F is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map**

Any idea how I can make QGIS operate from GUI (unity) with root privileges without having to open it via terminal and adding the sudo prefix?

I have attempted the solution provided below by edm, but the open window hangs and I recieve errors pertaining to klauncher: 
**Could not start process Cannot talk to klauncher: Not connected to D-Bus server.**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher

```
$ sudo qgis %F


Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_AU]
Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
kdeinit4: Shutting down running client.
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
```

QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.

```
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4(8139) VFolderMenu::loadDoc: Parse error in  "/home/lyndon/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu" , line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file" 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::init: The desktop entry file  "/usr/share/applications/evolution-data-server-uoa.desktop"  has Type= "Application"  but no Exec line 

kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/evolution-data-server-uoa.desktop" 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S0" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S1" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S2" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S3" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S4" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S5" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S6" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S7" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S8" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S9" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S10" but doesn't define it 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::init: The desktop entry file  "/usr/share/applications/unity-scope-gdrive.desktop"  has Type= "Application"  but no Exec line 

kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/unity-scope-gdrive.desktop"
```

kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::init: The desktop entry file  "/usr/share/applications/updf.desktop"  has Type= " Application"  instead of "Application" or "Service"

```
kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/updf.desktop"
```

kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::init: The desktop entry file  "/usr/share/applications/unity-lens-photos.desktop"  has Type= "Application"  but no Exec line

```
kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/unity-lens-photos.desktop" 
kbuildsycoca4(8139) kdemain: Emitting notifyDatabaseChanged ("servicetypes", "xdgdata-mime", "services", "apps")
Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Warning: Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Warning: Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Have you run other KDE applications as root (e.g. using sudo)? Have you run QGIS as root?

Comment: Yes, edited the above post with output. Seems to open files now, but has new errors. Also trying to figure out how to open it via unity with sudo privileges.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run QGIS as root. I think you've corrupted your KDE profile by running some KDE application as root. If you don't know which one, or can't tell us, then I can only suggest removing all of .kde, and starting again. Don't run KDE (or GTK/Gnome) applications as root. If you absolutely need to, use kdesudo / gksu as the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something related to permissions

```
kbuildsycoca4: ERROR creating database '/home/lyndon/.kde/cache-Gerhard-ThinkPad-W530/ksycoca4'! Insufficient permissions in target directory.
```

After seeing the output of

```
ls -l /home/lyndon/.kde/cache-Gerhard-ThinkPad-W530/
```

I think that you should change the owner of your files:

```
chown -R lyndon:lyndon /home/lyndon/.kde/cache-Gerhard-ThinkPad-W530/
```

Don't launch normal applications as root, there is not need at all to do that. I don't know also why are you using **%F** as a parameter when launching qgis. qgis is trying to interpret %F as a file to open.

Comment: Had to run that command with sudo prefix (might be an indicator of permissions issues?)

result:
`total 10320`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10547304 Apr 25  2013 icon-cache.kcache`

Comment: I have edited the initial post with full output. It appears I can run QGIS and open files and add layers without crashing, however I encounter a new error message. 
Trying to find out how to make QGIS open on nautilus with root privileges permenantely.

Comment: I edit my post, don't launch it as root, change the owner of the files

Comment: Brilliant, your last post (edit) has solved the problem! 

Much appreciated!!